# How put db connection in seperate file and use in another file in python

Tags: python

Hi i have problem regarding db connection. i want to put db connection in seprate file and can use in multiple files.

i have tried this

**connection.py**

```
import pymysql
import mysql.connector

class Connection:

    def __init__(self):
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", db="")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        return cur, conn
```

**main.py**

```
import connection

cur, conn = connection.Connection()
```

**Error**

```
cur, conn = connection.Connection()
TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'tuple'
```

Comment: You want a function, not a class…!?

Comment: The error message is explicit: the special `__init__` method is expected to return `None` (or not use `return` at all which is equivalent)

Comment: I'd suggest you use a [config](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) file instead, but otherwise just use a simple function like deceze suggested and you're fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

connection.py

```
import pymysql
import mysql.connector

def get_connection():
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", db="")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    return cur, conn
```

---

main.py

```
import connection

cur, conn = connection.get_connection()
```

---

Comment: Great, and then, how to close the connection in a function in the connection.py?

Comment: @herhor67 You can close the connection by `conn.close()` However, it is not appropriate because if you close the connection in `get_connection` function, you can't use it.

Comment: That was my point. It would be great to have an `init` and `deinit` functions, but when done in this way, you need to pass the `conn` variable to the `deinit`... God I hate Python.